# How to configure htaccess for localhost?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, localhost

I am working on a project maintenance where, I need to configure htaceess file to run project on localhost, because I have created a virtual host to run the project.

I have following code -

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(?!(text1|text2|text3)\.html|common-secure\.php|images\/|css-secure\/|javascript\/).* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteRule ^index.(.*)\.html$ index.php?langurl=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^city/(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.html$ city.php?cityurl=$1&langurl=$2&page=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}


#Other rules
```

I replaced last 4th and 5th line above by following -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

But, still not able to load the js plugins.
Also, not getting query string parameters (like 'langurl') into $_GET.

What am I missing/went wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: What URL are you sending to your web server?

Comment: @anubhava : its http://mysite.local/abc/value1/value2/... which is supposed to be converted to http://mysite.local/abc.php?param1=value1&param2=value2...

Comment: But I don't see any rule in your `.htaccess` which is adding param1, param2 etc to your query string.

Comment: @anubhava - I edited question. Check the rule just above the '#Other rules' line.

Comment: Ok as per last rule URL should always be ending with `.html`. But your  example is `http://mysite.local/abc/value1/value2/`

Answer (score 1):

You missing to add directory of your website in `RewriteBase`

```
RewriteBase /projectfolder/
```